# Android 2D graphics programming

Tags: android, opengl-es

What is the difference between [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and OpenGL for doing 2D graphics with Android?

Does Canvas use OpenGL in the background?  Are there cases where OpenGL might be slower than Canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas does not use OpenGL, it uses the software rendering library called Skia.